# passing a std::list to in to a thread make the data invalidate

Tags: c++, multithreading, network-programming

I wanted to pass a std::list pointer in to a thread and within that thread to do some processing with those objects . but when i debugged i saw the casting was ok but the data pointing to garbage .. i am posting my original code please explain

```
//this thread is reponsible for cleaning client objects which are no longer usable 
unsigned int __stdcall ConnectionCleanerThread(void *pData)
{

    std::list<ConnectionToClient *> * list = (std::list<ConnectionToClient *> * )pData;

    std::list<ConnectionToClient *>::const_iterator curOb = list->begin();

    ConnectionToClient * pCur = NULL;

    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        puts("Cleaner is running..");

        while (curOb != list->end())
        {
            pCur = (*curOb);
            printf("curretly searching con IP %s \n",pCur->GetIP());

            if ((*curOb)->IsThreadExited())
            {
                printf("The connection object for %s is removed \n",pCur->GetIP());
                list->remove(pCur);
                delete pCur;

            }

            curOb++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide code where you pass this list pointer as a parameter?

Comment: HANDLE clenerThreadHandler =(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,
            0,
            ConnectionCleanerThread,
            pClientList,
            0,
            0);

Comment: when i debug the loop always stays in the exiting condition.meaning there is no items in the list.. that shouldnt be the case since the list has some items in itpClientList is defined as follows



std::list <ConnectionToClient*> * pClientList;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the call to `_beginthreadex`.  Where does `pclientList` come from?  Does the pointed-to object last for the lifetime of the thread?  (What frees the memory?)  Also, can any other thread modify the list?  If so, you need to wrap all access to the list with a mutex.

Comment: What is the point of the `while (true)`?  Note that you never reset `curOb` to the start of the list?  Have you just run to the end (on the first time round the `while(true)`), and then you just sit at the end?

Comment: Curob is pointing to the beggining of the list.. Thats a thread code which needs to run indefinietly

Comment: The data is not touched by any other thread the list is simply invalidated after pasing to beginthreadex

Comment: When the data isn't touched by other threads, why is there a check `if ((*curOb)->IsThreadExited())`?

Comment: dear martin. please observe the cord .. curob is pointed to the beggining of the list through an iterator

Comment: I found the bug.. it was nothing related to threading and data protection. it was just a logical bug.. in the inner loop .. we need to set the cur object to the first element of the list .. the cleaner works as expected.. thank you all for your prompt replies